# Outputting a list to a row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
data1 # thousands of (784,1)
data2 # same number of (10,1)

with open(<file>,'w') as f:
    for idx,single_d1 in enumerate(data1):
        f.write(str(single_d1) + "\n"+str(data2[idx]) + "\n")
```

This works faster than zip(data1,data2), np.savetxt or with the package csv (order of magnitude).

data2 is output as I want, full list per line.
But data1 is seemingly cut off randomly after 7 (most of the time, a number of lines it's a slightly different number - most of the values are `0` in `single_d1`, when it isn't the line length is slightly (1/2/3) longer).
That results in it taking 100+ rows instead of the one I want.

I've tried `writelines` but that leads to the same! Maybe I've got a really dumb mistake, but I'm not finding it...

Comment: it doesn't work faster then `zip`, `np.savetxt` or `csv` module - because it doesn't work at all :) You don't get correct file.

Comment: Why would I lie? It works. I get the output I want except for what I mentioned.

Comment: maybe create file using `csv` module and compare it with your file. Maybe you find difference and it helps you.

Comment: In the csv documentation they use `with open() as` etc. Nevermind I don't see how opening the file differently will change the process of writing it. I am using `file.csv` you know lol. You are aware that's not the actual code right?

Comment: you are missing a `)` after `str(data2[idx]` and are the odd results based on what is sent to the file or checking the values of `data1` and `data2` right before writing them to the file and comparing them to the contents of the file?

Comment: I thought you know how to create correct file using `csv` module and you don't use it only because it is too slow.

Comment: `single_d1` and `data2[idx]` are both lists of the size mentioned in OP. In fact in the csv file since all I'm doing is converting it to `str` one can see that im putting lists in; `data[idx]` is just  `[<10 numbers separated by . since ndarray>]`, exactly as it should be. `single_d1` is the same, except for the fact it's not all on one line...

Comment: If speed is really an issue and you have very narrow needs, simpler code will probably be faster than a full implementation, yes.  The CSV module takes care of stuff like properly quoting values which contain the delimiter (comma by default) which your code doesn't attempt to do, for example.